# Is there a way to write a macro that knows how many times another macro has been used?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have something like the following, which I'm not satisfied with:

```
#define BEGIN {

#define END_1 };
#define END_2 END_1 };
#define END_3 END_2 };
// ... (possibly more of these) ...

#define END(x) END_ ## x

int main()
{
    BEGIN
    BEGIN
    BEGIN
    END(3) // <- I don't want to pass the 3 here

    BEGIN
    BEGIN
    END(2) // <- I don't want to pass the 2 here
}
```

And I would like to rewrite the definition of `BEGIN` and/or `END` so that the latter doesn't require to take an argument.

I believe this cannot be done, but I'm not very experienced with the **C** preprocessor. Is there at least any way to get closer to my goal than the example I posted?

Comment: Every time you call "BEGIN", call a i++ too and at last pass the END(i). Just an advise.

Comment: @Abhineet: I really don't understand what you're suggesting :( Could you show what you mean with some compiling code?

Comment: Wat, seriously? You're using... macros... for braces...?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 6):

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)  and MSVC offer a non-standard `__COUNTER__` macro that increments with each use. However, there is no way to reset it.

Whatever you are attempting should probably be done another way.

Answer (score 3):

Following may help:
It uses `#include` instead of direct macro...

begin.h :

```
#if !defined(BEGIN_COUNT)
# define BEGIN_COUNT 1
#elif BEGIN_COUNT == 1
# undef BEGIN_COUNT
# define BEGIN_COUNT 2
#elif BEGIN_COUNT == 2
# undef BEGIN_COUNT
# define BEGIN_COUNT 3
// And so on
#else
# error "Hard coded limit reached for BEGIN_COUNT"
#endif

// The token to add:
{
```

end.h :

```
#if !defined(BEGIN_COUNT)
# error "unbalanced #include begin.h/end.h"
#elif BEGIN_COUNT == 1
// The token to add:
}
#elif BEGIN_COUNT == 2
// The tokens to add:
} }
#elif BEGIN_COUNT == 3
// The tokens to add:
} } }
#else
# error "Hard coded limit reached for BEGIN_COUNT"
#endif

// reset counter
# undef BEGIN_COUNT
```

And then use it that way:

```
int main()
{
    #include "begin.h"
    #include "begin.h"

    #include "end.h" // close the 2 'begin'

    #include "begin.h"
    #include "end.h" // close the last 'begin'
    return 0;
}
```